# Define an update function that shows the next n points in the bokeh graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, graph, bokeh

Can someone help me define a function  on how to go to the next n in a bokeh graph

```
toggle_next = Toggle(label='Toggle Next', button_type='success')

def update_next():
"""This function shows the next 10 points in the data"""


toggle_next.on_click(update_next)
```

Comment: @bigreddot can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change `x_range`:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Button, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import row
from random import random

p = figure(x_range=(0, 10))
p.line(list(range(1000)), [random() for _ in range(1000)])

b = Button(label='Show next 10', callback=CustomJS(args=dict(xr=p.x_range), code="""
    xr.start = xr.end;
    xr.end = xr.end + 10;
"""))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, it works well. Is there a way to make it go to the next datapoint labeled '0' instead of just iterating to the next 10. thank you !

Comment: @Victor I'm not sure what you mean by "next datapoint labeled '0'". Can you elaborate and/or add some code to the question?

Comment: as you can see my graph consists of '0' and '1'. And now that the x_range is limited from 0 to 10, instead of clicking "Show next 10 ", I want it to be "show next '0'

Comment: @Victor I see. It's a separate question, unrelated to the one you asked initially. In the `CustomJS` code in my answer, you can just scan the data to find the next 0 point closest to the current range, and set `start` and `end` to the found locations. It's easier to be done when using a `ColumnDataSource` since you can easily access it from the callback. You can find more examples here: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html